# How do I send two different data types in my main method to another method?

Tags: java

**What the main method calls for:**

- ask the user what his name is
- assign the user's name to variable of type String called myName
- ask the user what his body temperature is
- assign the number entered by the user to a variable of type double
  named myTemperature
- call the determineFever method, sending it the value of the variables
  myName and myTemperature

**What the determineFever method calls for:**

- this method has two parametesr: a String called yourName and a
  double, named bodyTemperature
- this method returns nothing
- this method says "Hello *_*_, you have a fever. Take some aspirin."
  if the value of the variable bodyTemperature is above 98.6
- Fill in the blank with the value of the variable yourName
- if the bodyTemperature is less than or equal to 98.6, say "Hello *_*,
  you have no fever. You may go to the movies."
- Fill in the blank with the value of the variable yourName

**My main method:**

```
String myName;
double myTemperature;
System.out.print("\nWhat is your name? ");
myName = readit.next();
System.out.print("\nWhat is your body temperature? ");
myTemperature = readit.nextDouble();
determineFever();
```

**Determine Fever method:**

```
public static void determineFever() {
    String message;
    if (bodyTemperature <= 98.6) {
        message = "Hello " + yourName + ", you have no fever. You may go to the movies.";
    } // end if
    else {
        message = "Hello " + yourName + ", you have a fever. Take some aspirin.";
    } // end else
    System.out.println(message);
} // end determineFever method
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass parameters to a method?

Comment: Is your question how to pass the name and temperature to the function `determineFever`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to:

```
public static void determineFever(double bodyTemp, String name)
{
    String message;
    if (bodyTemp <= 98.6)
    {
        message = "Hello " + name + ", you have no fever. You may go to the movies.";
    } // end if
    else
    {
        message = "Hello " + name + ", you have a fever. Take some aspirin.";
    } // end else
    System.out.println(message);
} // end determineFever method
```

And then, in main, change `determineFever();` to `determineFever(bodyTemperature, yourName);`

Like this.  I highly recommend referring to these variables by a different name within the method (edit: I changed them in the code block above).  Also, my personal preference would be to change the return type to `String` and return `message` and print it in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to pass value to a function. This is done by adding `parameters` to a function, and looks like this: `public static void determinFever(String yourName, double bodyTemperature){`. Then in your `main` function just put `determineFever(myName, myTemperature);`